# Not able to view the uploaded file on browser

Tags: node.js, express

**I have a working code - when it comes to uploading the file** ::

```
var express=require('express');
var mysql=require('mysql');
var fs=require('fs');
var http=require('http');
var crypto=require('crypto');

var app=express();

var connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'****',
    password:'****',
    database:'posting_only_image_DB'
});

connection.connect();

app.set('port',process.env.PORT||1234);

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public/images'));

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.post('/Details/',function(req,res,next){

    var file_name=req.files.key.originalFilename;
    console.log(file_name);

    crypto.randomBytes(8, function(ex, buf) {

        var array     = req.files.key.originalFilename.split('.');
        var type      = array[array.length - 1];
        var name      = buf.toString('hex') + '.' + type;

        fs.rename(req.files.key.path, './public/images/' + name, function(e) {
            next(e, name);
        });
    });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port'+app.get('port'));
});
```

---

**I make a request as below while uploading the file**::

**however my query works and i can see the file with unique id in server disk in location `/public/images`** .... with the file name:: `8ce456dc55575888.jpg`

---

**Now say if i want to test it and i want to view the uploaded file** :: I five a Url request to below for the browser

```
http://-----URL----/Details/8ce456dc55575888.jpg
```

**I get the error on browser as** ::

```
Cannot GET /Details/8ce456dc55575888.jpg
```

---

**How to resolve this ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a `GET` route for `/Details/8ce456dc55575888.jpg`.

If you want the static middleware to handle those requests, you need to configure it properly:

```
app.use('/Details', express.static(__dirname+'/public/images'));
```

This means that requests for:

```
/Details/8ce456dc55575888.jpg
```

Will be mapped to:

```
{{__dirname}}/public/images/8ce456dc55575888.jpg
```

You can use that in addition to the other `express.static` that you're using.

Comment: Perfect ! .... Also thanks for such a good and detailed information ..... this helps for newbies for ExpressJS